# Infinity loop while resolving intercept-url spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I m quite new in spring security. I m doing following code.

```
<http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/sign" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/signup" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/panel/signin" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/singout" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/panel/**" access="hasRole(ROLE_USER)" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <form-login login-page="/signin" default-target-url="/home" authentication-failure-url="/signin" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </http>

     <authentication-manager>  
            <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userLoginService">  
                <password-encoder hash="plaintext"/>  
            </authentication-provider>  
        </authentication-manager>
```

I want to open signin, signup, /panel/sigin, /panel/signup for anonymous user but want to restrict rest of url. But when i use this code it shows me "Infinity loop" error on browser.

When i remove one line that is 
then its comes fine but not restrict the url.

can some body correct this code.

Comment: I don't see `/panel/signup` covered by a specific rule? Which URL gives you the infinite redirect loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to acces some secured url, the application redirects you to the login page, but since `/singin` is also secured(the last filter `/**` cathces it) the app tries to redirect to the login page again and again.

Add `<intercept-url pattern="/singin" filters="none" />` or `permitAll`  at the top.

```
    <http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/singin" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/sign" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/signup" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/panel/signin" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/singout" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/panel/**" access="hasRole(ROLE_USER)" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <form-login login-page="/signin" default-target-url="/home" authentication-failure-url="/signin" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </http>
```